# Mathematical constant cannot be accessed

Tags: c++, c++20

```
#include<numbers>

int main(){
    double x = pi;
}
```

on C++ 20 throws the error:

```
error: 'pi' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm fairly new to C++, what could be wrong?

---

What was wrong? The compiler wasn't ready for this. I updated it and added `-std=c++20` at compile time.

Comment: It's in a namespace... `std::numbers::pi`

Comment: `constexpr double π = std::numbers::pi;` ... and then you can watch the ASCII-only -v- all-of-Unicode war explode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The constant `pi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/constants):

1. Requires C++20
2. And is defined in the `std::numbers` namespace.

You must verify that your compiler implements at least this part of C++20, and provide any required compilation flags for C++20 support, as well as either replace the reference to fully-qualified `std::numbers::pi`, or add `using namespace std::numbers`, or maybe a few other aliasing alternatives that you will find explained in your C++ textbook.

Answer (score 2):

**This one should work**. Tested on `GCC 11.11` `C++20`

```
#include <iostream>
#include<numbers>

using namespace std::numbers;

int main(){
    double x = pi;
    
    std::cout << "The answer is " << x ;
}
```